# javascript function call in conditional not being called if first returns false

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

My problem is a seemingly simple one.

I have two functions, function_a() and function_b() which show/hide a div, and return boolean values.

I have a conditional

```
if(function_a() && function_b())
{
     //do stuff
}
```

However if function_a() returns false, function_b() is seemingly not executed at all.
I however want them both to run because i want them to show/hide their respective divs.

Why does the second function not run if the first returns false, and how do i achieve what i want?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, that's called short-circuiting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second function will never get executed if first condition is false because you have && condition. That is how && works.

**&& is logical operator and evaluates the left side of the operation, if it's true, it continues and evaluates the right side other wise it will stop and return false.**

if you want to execute both then store the return value in some variable and then put the logic

```
var a  = function_a();
var b  = function_b();

if(a && b){
 //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? My answer is identical. No downvote for me?

Comment: As you were first ive voted yours correct. Are there any problems associated with doing it like this?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to assign them to variables before testing 'truthiness':

```
var a = function_a(),
    b = function_b();

if(a && b)
{
 //do stuff
}
```

This way they are both run and then the `if` statement can check for `true/false`.